# Does MagSafe enable the use of existing tripods?

Tags: iphone, camera, magsafe

There already exists a worldwide standard for connecting tripods—[1/4-20 UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripod_(photography)#Screw_thread)  screw—to cameras (the hole you see at the bottom of any camera made in the last few decades).

This is a silly little question, but somebody needs to ask it.

Are the MagSafe magnets in the iPhone 12 series strong enough to reliably hold the phone, *only through magnets*, to a tripod?

Otherwise it seems like an obvious contraption, one that enables users to use one of their existing tripods rather than acquire a tripod specifically for just this edition of this phone. (If you found such a contraption and have experience with it, please share.)

**Update**

We are unlikely to ever get even a hint from Apple that the magnets are strong enough for snapping to gadgets attached to a tripod or to ones attached to car vents, for the simple reason that Apple would be setting themselves up for yet-another frivolous class-action lawsuit, even if they used Neodymium magnets in the iPhone 12—especially with the still-fresh memory of the last outlandish MagSafe lawsuit. (After many years of use, I can attest that a MagSafe cable is much safer when perpendicular to a MacBook, because it snaps off much more easily when pulled, yet the lawsuit succeeded in proving exactly the opposite.)

In this question I'm soliciting anecdotal evidence that the magnets are usable for snapping on/off by a careful user (who of course takes his/her own risks).

**Update 2**

Quite likely this is a lot more handy for attaching the iPhone 12 to car vents, with the convenience of one-handed snapping on and off everytime you step in/out of the car, and the reduced risk of the phone falling only a short distance, likely on a carpet.

**Update 3**

Apple was not the first to bring to market (i)Phone magnetic cases and attachments with the [MagSafe](https://www.apple.com/shop/accessories/all/magsafe) line.

[Moft](https://www.moft.us) and [MagBak](https://magbak.com) also have offerings, possibly preceding Apple's.

It's still unclear whether anyone released a camera tripod magnetic attachment, or a car vent magnetic attachment.

Other options:

- [Peak Design](https://www.peakdesign.com/products/phone-mount)
- [Manfrotto](https://www.manfrotto.com/global/products/smartphones-action-cameras-drones/smartphone-accessories/)

Comment: Why not edit this to be a simple question and out all the answers, reasoning, experiments and measurements  in the answer section? This read more like a forum discussion or blog post than a question without chit chat per the  [tour]

Comment: @bmike Ah.. there you are... The question really "wants to be" whether there exists a _magnetic_ device to attach a MagSafe iPhone (i.e., 12) to a regular camera tripod. Googling suggests that such a device does not (yet) exist. Hence the present question is the prequel: would the magnet even be strong enough?

Comment: @bmike The difficulty, as clear from the current answer, is that the question ends up being subjective, but only because different users will have different risk tolerances for holding a phone through just a magnet about 5 or 6 ft above random ground via a tripod.

Comment: No worries. I’m not voting to close the question, just it might get better votes if it’s short and all the potential answers or half solutions are presented in the answer section. Feel free to not change anything while it remains open for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the MagSafe magnets in the iPhone 12 series strong enough to reliably hold the phone, only through magnets, to a tripod?

Magsafe is for ***charging*** not mounting; it helps align the charger.  Even if they are strong enough to hold the phone, are you willing to put a $700USD (or more) device hanging by just a magnet?  You use the 1/4" or 3/8" screw posts to securely hold camera gear with proper mounts (hot/cold shoe), why would you risk your phone this way?

> Otherwise it seems like an obvious contraption, one that enables users to use one of their existing tripods rather than acquire a tripod specifically for just this edition of this phone.

I don't see what MagSafe has to do with a tripod in any way.  You didn't need MagSafe to use your phone with a tripod before MagSafe.  I literally just purchased this Manfrotto Mount (see below) to hold my iPhone on a tripod and additional 1/4" posts to attach LED panels.

[image: Manfrotto Camera Mount]

Comment: That is precisely my question. If the magnets are strong enough, I'll gladly hang my phone to stabilize it while taking photos (even fancier image stabilizations are no match to a tripod). If these are weak magnets, then I wouldn't consider using them to hang the phone.

Comment: Magsafe is supposed to be good enough to use as a car mount, so I don't see using it as a tripod mount would be too dangerous. Here's a bunch of camera mounts, inc extra cold-shoe & tripod adapting with multiple thread choices - https://www.theverge.com/2020/11/2/21545486/moment-magsafe-iphone-12-case-mount-announced TBH I don't see it as inventing a better mouse-trap, but if it can be done, someone will sell it.

Comment: See... It's "should be" and "if they are strong enough."  You have to line it up properly to get a good mount and you're literally hanging your iDevice on "I hope it is..."  It's also not the iPhone you have to worry about, but the quality of the magnets in the mount.  There are cheaper and more secure mounts already on the market.

Comment: It's not something I'm ever likely to need, so it's all theoretical to me. What I normally put on top of my Manfrotto is, unsurprisingly… a camera ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Re "supposed to be good enough": Great, but can you back this up with a pointer—one not from the Moment Corp. These are two use-cases though. A car vibrates, but the drop distance is small. A properly weighed tripod doesn't vibrate, but the drop distance could be as tall as 6ft/~2m.

Comment: I soooooo knew the thread would go here:  *Great, but can you back this up with a pointer—one not from the Moment Corp*  This statement is exactly why I wrote my answer the way I did.

Comment: I have read your answer as "I don't really know. I suspect that the magnets are not strong enough" (although your wording is different). Now I see that thats's exactly what you wanted to write.

Comment: As any one of my  lenses is worth more than an iPhone 12 Pro Max, I'm not going to be entrusting that task to magnets. It's not research I need to be doing. If you don't trust the products, don't buy them. They're essentially 'fluff' anyway. Buy Alan's grippy thing, it will work on a 12 and anything earlier too.

Comment: Anyway, I appreciate your eagerness to help (I'm quite familiar with your answers here). I'd like to solicit Mike's opinion. Maybe he read something that's definitive on this issue.

Comment: Read my answer as "why would you risk your **expensive** phone on the unknown holding strength of a magnet when there are far better options availabe"

Comment: @Tetsujin Re: "lenses is worth more than an iPhone 12 Pro Max" What am I missing? Who talked about holding our SLRs on magnets?

Comment: No-one, but this comment thread has already gone so far off the rails it's in danger of drowning...

Comment: @Allan Re: ""why would you risk your expensive phone" It's a simple reason: _extreme_ convenience. The use of a camera tripod always adds a few seconds to attach/detach the plate. I very often simply pack my SLR with the plate attached. Ugly, but necessary. Here and now we have the option of snapping the phone in and out. When we pick it up, no face plate is attached to it.

Comment: @Sam I don't care what my gear looks like, just the finished product.  To each his own, but I'm answer the question as written "are the **MagSafe** magnets strong enough"  I doubt the ones in the phone are by themselves - the tripod mount will matter.  And for that matter - easy on/off means easier way to accidentally knock it out of the mount and onto the ground.

Comment: I meant bmike, not Mike.